# In-app purchases of an app downloaded from a different country

Tags: itunes, applications, ios-appstore, in-app-purchase

A few months ago, I purchased a number of applications from iTunes US using a US-based credit card even though I'm not from the USA; from the PH, actually. (I used AmEx Virtual Pay offered by my local telco provider)

Now, I recently moved to Japan and upon seeing these iTunes cards on the convenience stores, I am really tempted to buy some. (I don't have a JP-based credit card and I cannot, should not, must not use my PH-based CC to do purchases).

Which brings me now to my problem, I want to do some in-app purchases on the apps I purchased on the iTunes US using (possibly) the iTunes card JP. Is this possible? Will changing just the country of my iTunes work? Since I'm thinking that even though the app was downloaded from a different country, after all, I'm still using the same account.

I understand that if I decide to download new paid apps, I could just change my country to Japan and use the iTunes card, but will this work with in-app purchases?

Let me know if my question's unclear. Thanks.

Comment: In-app purchases must be made with the same account that purchased the app. I am not sure if changing the country on that account would affect your ability to make in-app purchases, though.

Comment: The question was more will iTunes card purchased in Japan work on US account. Which I think will not, but I don't have any hard evidence. What is sure is when you change the country, it's like you are on a brand new account, your apps will stay tied to the previous country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it won't work. From the [Apple Support pages](https://support.apple.com/en-lb/HT201389):

> After you change the country of your account, you won't see the items you purchased from the previous country’s store in the Purchased section.

Comment: I sure wish Apple would make iTunes store accessible internationally and not just locked per country. I've read that there's this licensing thing so Apple can't really do a thing about it. Oh well. So much for the iTunes cards.